# replace square bracket & curly brackets to round brackets in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this

```
var data = "{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*69"
```

I need to replace all the square bracket & curly brackets to round brackets in javascript or jquery

I have tried this

```
.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'')
```

but it replaces all the open and close brackets parallel

Expected result is = `"(45)*(52)*(45)*(52)*(45)*(52)*69"`

Any ideas ?

Comment: `.replace(/[\[\{](\d+)[\]\}]/g, "($1)")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a simple way you can use

```
"{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*69".split(/[\{\[]/).join('(').split(/[\}\]]/).join(')')
```

Comment: Thank you Harpreet.. This is what i expected.. A SINGLE LINE CODE !! Its AWESOME +1

Answer (score 3):

You can call `.replace()` with a function as the second parameter.
With this function you can create a new substring which will be used as replacement.

[`str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, flags])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> *function (replacement)*
>   A function to be invoked to create the new
>   substring (to put in place of the substring received from parameter
>   1). The arguments supplied to this function are described in the "Specifying a function as a parameter" section below.
>
> *Specifying a function as a parameter*
>   You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the
>   function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The
>   function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement
>   string. (Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do not
>   apply in this case.) Note that the function will be invoked multiple
>   times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in
>   the first parameter is global.

```
"[abc]".replace(/\[|\]/g, function(m) {
    var replacements = {"[": "(", "]": ")"}; return replacements[m];
});
```

Comment: Complete answer: 
"{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*69".replace(/(\[|\])|(\{|\})/g, function(m) {
    var replacements = {"[": "(", "]": ")", "{":"(", "}":")"}; return replacements[m];
});

Answer (score 2):

in one replace

```
var data = "{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*69";
data = data.replace(/[\[\{](\d+)[\]\}]/g, "($1)")
```

Though it will also replace [123} and {123] with (123) ... so not technically correct

if you want to only replace "correctly" formatted input, you need two replace calls

```
data = data.replace(/[\{](\d+)[\}]/g, "($1)").replace(/[\[](\d+)[\]]/g, "($1)")
```

I think

Comment: Thanks for your support :)  It really helps me to gain a valuable knowledge +1

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `RegExp` `/(.\d{2}.)/` to match any character before two digits , two digits, any character ; `.match()` to match digits , return replacement string

```js
var data = "{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*{45}*[52]*69";
var res = data.replace(/(.\d{2}.)/g, function(match) {
  return "(" + match.match(/\d+/)[0] + ")"
});
document.body.textContent = res;
```